# Jquery control parent window from child window

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm playing around with a few ideas for a project, and one of them needs to somehow have communication between 2 different browser pages/windows/tabs. My goal is this:

I have a main page that has a link that opens a new tab/window. In that window, there is the choice to 'navigate' a part of the main page. The issue is, to my knowledge, there are no physical ties between open windows (and no handle on the 'parent' window accessible by the child).

I've been trying to use opener to reference the parent window, but functions and elements are not responding to my calls from the child.

Is there any way for a child/other window to access elements/functions on a parent window?

I'm attempting to avoid using simulated tabs/frames (which would be easy enough to just reference the parent, or window element to accomplish the goal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, actually that is possible.  If you use `window.open()` in JavaScript, you can use `window.opener.` and submit whatever requests you would normally make.  Like:

`window.opener.document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "hello";`

or using jQuery,

`$(window.opener.document).find('#tableInParent').html("hello");`

Read more here: http://wisercoder.com/javascript-jquery-parent-windows/

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/4FBZv/)

I hope this helps!

Comment: I eventually managed to get it working (the method i was using to open the window previously, was not via window.open() ).

Thanks for the pointers!